# how resolve java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to create an rmi application : the client transfer  file to the serve. But , when running the code i get security manager exception. 
Here is the client side :

```
  import java.rmi.Naming;
  import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class StartFileClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    try{
        FileClient c=new FileClient("imed");            
        FileServerInt server=(FileServerInt)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/abc");
        server.login(c);
        System.out.println("Listening.....");           
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);           
        while(true){
            String line=s.nextLine();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the server side :

```
 import java.rmi.Naming;
public class StartFileServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{

        java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

        FileServer fs=new FileServer();
        fs.setFile("itcrowd.avi");          
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/abc", fs);
        System.out.println("File Server is Ready");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Also, i create a file  security.policy

```
  grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

};

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your policy file isn't being found. You need to specify its location via the `java.security.policy` system property.

BUT Unless you're using the codebase feature, remove the security manager.

Comment: i put the    policy file in  my folder package.

Comment: i remove it . But i get  the same error : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve") ..

Comment: Putting the policy file into your 'folder package' won't accomplish anything in particular, and neither will removing it. You don't seem to have actually read my answer.

Comment: sorry , but how can i  specify its  location ? , do you mean in the sever code or where ?

Comment: By setting the system property I named, in whichever JVM is using it. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: I think my problem is when i run the app , i run it normally as a java application  ,  normally i have to run it using console ??

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with it. Your .policy file isn't being found, and you don't need the security manager anyway.